# Rails link_to destroy method fails due to invalid authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, hyperlink, haml, destroy

I have the following haml code which generates a button:

```
= link_to 'Delete',
        MODEL_path(MODEL),
        class: 'data-type-button btn btn-negative',
        data: { confirm: 'delete it now!!! ... ?' },
        method: :delete
```

After pressing the delete button generated, and confirming via the popup that I do want to proceed with the deletion, I am brought to an error screen. This screen tells me that I have an invalid authenticity token. The same code where `link_to` is replaced with `button_to`, however, works as it should and the item is deleted.

I want this to be a `link_to` and not a `button_to` because of the way that the resulting HTML code lines up. How can I get the `link_to` to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Confirm you have the csrf meta tag in your layout and in the HTML HEAD section.

```
= csrf_meta_tag
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Are you saying that if I put that in my application.html.haml file, then I would not have had any of these issues with the auth token?

Comment: The javascript of the link_to and delete method will use the header meta tag. `button_to` adds a hidden field to pass the auth token.

Comment: @ThomasDeranek This should be the accepted answer, because it's the most ideal way to handle this.

Comment: This will work assuming you are using jquery-rails gem.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, `link_to` passes parameters via the contents inside of the parenthesis following the path. So in order to get the authenticity token to be passed as a parameter while also using a `link_to`, you can use the following modification of that code

```
= link_to 'Delete',
        MODEL_path(id: MODEL.id, authenticity_token: form_authenticity_token),
        class: 'data-type-button btn btn-negative',
        data: { confirm: 'Delete it now!!! ... ?' },
        method: :delete
```

I actually knew the answer when I posted the question, but after spending a lot of time trying to figure this out and not finding the solution directly on google anywhere, I wanted to post my solution to help any other lost souls out there. I don't know if that is bad practice on this website or not, but if it helps someone then I'm okay with it.

Comment: I found that two things are needed to get the Dstroy link_to links to work:  (1) <%= javascript_include_tag :application %> in the <head> section of application.html.erb and (2) the authenticity_token that is suggested by Thomas here.

Comment: I just stumbled into the same problem using the `link_to name, url, method: :delete` in Rails 6.1.1. `csrf_meta_tags` is present in `<head>` and `@rails/ujs` is running, imported via `javascript_pack_tag "application"`. Rails does make a `DELETE` request but throws an `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error. After manually adding the `form_authenticity_token` to the delete link path params (as suggested above) the `DELETE` request passes. This is okay as a temporary solution, but where does this come from? Any news on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A long time later, but found the following that solved my issue:

`link_to(method: xxx)` generates a link that works with javascript but doesn't degrade well to no-javascript:

see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to, note under options for method:

> Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET....

`button_to(method: xxx)` does generate a form which works without javascript as well.

This difference can come back to bite you in odd ways (e.g. a rack-test system test with a link_to(method) might not work if you have forgery protection turned off for tests, whereas the equivalent does work for the button_to(method))

And as a note, it's quite possible to style a button inside of a so it looks the same as a link. Super easy with bootstrap (`.btn.btn-link` or whatever makes `a` and `button/input[type=submit]` display the same). The automatically provided class of `button_to` on the form element helps too.